# how to use apollo graphql query using GET method in angular 5

Tags: angular, get, graphql, apollo-client

What is the query format to send the GET request using Apollo GraphQL in Angular5?

I've used

```
    this.querySubscription = this.apollo.watchQuery<any>({
         query: gql`
         query listSchemaAttributes($schemaDomain: String!) {
            query listSchemaAttributes(schemaDomain: $schemaDomain) {
                 type
                 uniqueName
                 isList
             }
         }
       `,
         variables: {
             schemaDomain: "abc",
         },
     })
         .valueChanges
        .subscribe(({data}) => {
            this.currentUser = data.currentUser;
        });
```

this request is sent as POST method when i check in network tab, but i need to send it as GET method. Please help me out on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apollo-angular-link-http` and it's `method` option to set it to GET

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/tree/master/packages/apollo-angular-link-http#options